# MDX show all sales until now

Tags: mdx

i have a huge table of cashflows that means there are +int values for income and -int values for outcome.

I have MeasureGroup for Sum the amount of money.

I now want to display not only the sum of money per month but also the sum of all the past time until the current month so like that:

```
Month  MoneyAmount  Total
1      20           20
2      -10          10
3      5            15
4     -10           5
```

So i know for the first part its just like

```
select [Measures].[Money] on 0,
[Date].[Month].Members on 1
From MyCube
```

but how can i add the sum column?

i thought about something like SUM(  { NULL : [Date].[Month].CurrentMember } , [Measures].[Money] ) but that didnt work as well :(

Answer (score 0):

In MDX, the total is already there. You do not have to do complex calculations to get it.

But it depends on your exact hierarchy structure how the `All` member is called. If you have a date user hierarchy named `[Date].[Date]`, and it has a month level named `[Date].[Date].[Month]`, then the all member of the hierarchy would probably be called something like `[Date].[Date].[All]`. If `[Month]` is an attribute hierarchy of the Date dimension, then the "all member" would probably be called `[Date].[Month].[All]`. In the latter case, the all member would already be the first member of the set `[Date].[Month].Members`. As you are asking the question, I am assuming this is not the case, and you are using a user hierarchy. Then you could change your MDX query to

```
select [Measures].[Money] on 0,
Union([Date].[Month].Members, { [Date].[Date].[All] }) on 1
From MyCube
```

Please note that you can change the name of the All member in the property settings of a dimension when designing an Analysis Services dimension, hence I cannot know the definitive name without knowing the details of this setting in your cube. So you might have to adapt the name of the all member.

You can find this name out in SQL Server Management Studio in an MDX window as follows:  open the hierarchy that you are using, and then open the "Members" node, below which you should find the "All Member". You can drag this into your MDX statement, and the proper name will appear there.

Answer (score 0):

As in a running sum?

You need a calculated measure, like this:

```
With Member [Measures].[Running Sum] as Sum(  ( [Date].[Months].Members.Item(0) : [Date].[Months].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[Money])
Select [Date].[Months].Members on Rows,
{[Measures].[Money], [Measures].[Running Sum] } on Columns 
From [MyCube]
```